How to properly upload files using Rocket?
Looking for some variants how to upload file and meta-data in one request, I find out that I can use multipart/form-data content-type.
In rust rocket documentation, I found example where TempFile was used, but it's saved without any obvious file extension. Just like data-file.
Then I created a route and trying to get a file name (full, with extension), and then I saw .name and .raw_name methods.
First returns pure name without extension and the second returns &FileName, that I can perform to str (but it's equivalent to .name()).
Then I saw dangerous_unsafe_unsanitized_raw() method in documentation, and I don't get it, should I use it or no?
Maybe there is a more proper way how to upload files? (Like with Data<'_> but there are no methods to use with filename at all, and I should know proper file size.. ) or I shouldn't save files with obvious extension..?
Any suggestions, please?
Update:
#[post("/upload", data = <file>)]
async fn upload_route(data: TempFile<'_>) -> (Status, Value) {
    //I need to save file (ex. test.zip), somehow. For properly saving i need:
    //1) Filename (-> test)
    //2) File extension (-> .zip)
    let pure_name = file.name().unwrap();        //returns "test", but not .zip
    let file_name = file.raw_name().unwrap();    //returns &FileName("test.zip")
    let file_name = file_name.as_str().unwrap(); //returns "test" (I expected "test.zip"!)
    let real_full_name = file.raw_name().unwrap().dangerous_unsage_unsanitized_raw().as_str();
    data.persist_to("temp/dir/to/<filename>").await?;

    (Status::Ok, Value::String(String::from("File successfully saved")))   
}


What exactly have you tried? Please show us the code that in your opinion came closest to what you're trying to achieve, plus whatever errors (from cargo check, not from your IDE) you got while compiling, or if your code compiles without error, explain what you expect and what happens instead when you run the code.

@Jmb I have updated the topic and added code sample.
As you can see, i'm trying to save a file, but im using unsafe method. Like said in documentation, "Always prefer to use FileName::as_str()". So how should i get extension properly instead?

Looking at the source code file.name.unwrap() is equivalent to file.raw_name().unwrap().as_str().unwrap(). And the FileName::as_str docs do state that they strip the extension as part of the process for sanitizing the name.
You can get a safe name with as_str and use the content type to get a valid extension:
fn get_name (file: &TempFile<'_>) -> Option<String> {
    format!("{}.{}", file.name()?, file.content_type()?.extension()?)
}


I tried that, but it returns "bin". As an example, i tried to upload test.zip, but i got "bin" instead of ".zip".. so.. And yeah, i set content-type for my curl as multipart/form-data. Anyway it doesnt let me get a proper extension.. =(
(And another problem happened, if i use Form<TempFile<'r>> okapi swagger said that TempFile need to impl JsconSchema... Maybe i should look towards utoipa?)

You need to set the correct content-type for your file, so application/zip if you have a zip file. multipart/form-data is fine if you're posting a full form but then your file must be sent as a form part with the proper content-type (e.g. curl -F "zipfile=@test.zip;type=application/zip" http://example.com) and then of course your server must handle form data.

okay, i understand it now! Thank you a lot!!!
